# Is there a way to run a JUnit test for a particular class in IntelliJ without compiling the entire project?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

I have a project in IntelliJ that has a number of syntactically correct and incorrect classes and a unit test that I've written for a particular class.

Is there a way to execute the test even though other classes, completely independent from the current class I want to test, have errors that prevent the entire project from compiling?

The class I want to test has no compile-time errors. When I try to run the test, I'm directed to those other classes with syntax errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace the Before launch **Build** step with **Build, no error check**:

[image: no error check]

Do this change for the default JUnit configuration (under **Defaults** node in the tree on the left) so that it's applied to all the new JUnit run/debug configurations automatically.

You can also remove the **Build** step and compile the test files manually (from the file right click context menu):

[image: recompile]

Comment: Doesn't work well with latest version of IntelliJ (here 2023.2.2). I get `TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests`.