Executing Tests in IntelliJ IDEA with Project Compilation Errors: Seeking Solutions
I am attempting to execute test cases in IntelliJ IDEA, even though my project contains compilation errors. I have already implemented all the recommendations provided in this Stack Overflow thread. Enable Partial Compilation in IntelliJ IDEA
In Eclipse, I am able to run test cases without requiring a prior build or resolving compilation errors in unrelated parts of the project. However, achieving similar functionality in IntelliJ has been difficult.
If anyone has updated strategies or advanced configurations to bypass the build process and execute tests directly in IntelliJ, I would greatly appreciate your insights.
Thank you!

Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should specify what test framework you are using, such as JUnit5. As you may have noticed, the thread you link to is very old. I would advise focusing on fixing the compilation errors or creating stubs to temporarily replace illegal code, but if you really want to pursue partial compilation (which I haven't seen in IntelliJ), provide more specifics about your situation.

Some more relevant information that could be useful: what is your build system? If it's Gradle, do you have "Run tests using Gradle" set?

If you're not testing using Gradle, this question could be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680459/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-junit-test-for-a-particular-class-in-intellij-without-co
